# Multilanguage without url segments

Tags: localization

Is it possible to use craft multilanguage capabilities without `locale` url segments?

Example:

German: `domain.com/wetter`

English: `domain.com/weather`

I know this is pretty dangerous. If one forgets to translate the url everything will fall apart. But I wonder if it would be possible theoretically :)

Comment: In your mind the German language version will live at domain.com/wetter instead of domain.com/de, In tandem the English version will live at domain.com/wether instead of domain.com/en_us?  Or are you trying to eliminate both segments and when the user changes language the url is still just domain.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull data from entries by specifying a locale.

```
{% craft.entries.section('yourSection').locale('en_us') %}
```

Determine the locale you need by the custom segment.

```
{% set locales = {  'wetter': 'de', 'weather' : 'en_us' } %}
{% set segment = craft.request.firstSegment() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('yourSection').locale(locales[segment]) %}
```

The big issue you will have is translating strings for each language.  If you are not at **domain.com/de**, I believe, you won't receive the benefits of the translation files in *Craft/Translations*. You will need to build in your own mechanism to translate strings depending on the segment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insight. I guess I can live with locale url segments then :)